# Replaced SSD drive on MBPr shown as External

Tags: macos, mac, ssd

I replaced my internal MBPr SSD for an OCW Aura one.

It works great, but it's recognised as "External" (despite being installed internally), which means it shows up on Finder/Desktop as an external drive, and it even has the Eject button shown.

From a quick glance on the System Report, the issue should be that it's marked as "Removable Media: Yes". Any way to change that and have OS X see it properly as an internal drive?

I'm running the latest El Capitan version btw, and the drive is an OCW Aura 480.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, having had the same issue myself you need to erase and setup the drive again from scratch. It comes from the factory setup as you describe for whatever reason.
After backing up all your data (or if you already have a good backup or don't need one), follow these instructions:

Power off your Mac. Power on then immediately hold the Left Command, Option and R keys

This will Boot to Internet Recovery Mode on your Mac.

Once booted, go to Utilities, Terminal.

Inside Terminal type the following:

`diskutil unmountdisk disk0`

`gpt destroy /dev/disk0`

Close Terminal.

Open Disk Utility.

Click your OWC Aura drive on the left side, then choose the Erase Button.
Once erased, close disk utility and then choose Reinstall OS X and choose the newly reformatted volume.

You should note it appears as a regular internal drive now.

Comment: i booted from a usb drive not from the network but did exactly what you suggested, unmounted the disk then destroyed its GUID Partition Table and reformatted the disk; once mac os (sierra) was reinstalled, the disk still appeared as External. Any idea how to fix this differently ?

Answer (score 1):

I fought this issue for the weekend. The issue I ran into was that Windows 10 simply would not finish the installation after installing the OWC Aura 1TB SSD (PCI). It would stall at various % of "Getting files ready for installation" step. Nothing I tried worked.

What I ended up doing was taking an acronis trueimage 2017 clone of all of my disks. The important step is to make sure you have a valid recovery partition on OSX. This is very important because of the way that I got the disk set up. Once the acronis backup is finished, I set up an acronis universal boot media in OSX. This USB was vital. Once finished, I rebooted my MBPr. And booted from the universal boot media (acronis) and let acronis clone the backup to the new 1TB Aura. Once that was complete, I was able to boot perfectly into both OSX and Windows.

I still had the External disk issue though. In OSX I got the driver from OWC for 'bootcamp' here: [OWC Support Drivers Download](https://www.owcdigital.com/support/software-drivers.html)
Choose the correct one for you (Aura SSD for Mid-2013 and Later MacBook Air and MacBook Pro with Retina display). Then, install it in OSX. Upon rebooting, Disk Utility now displayed the OWC Aura SSD Media as "960.04 GB PCI Internal Physical Disk" where before it was always external. There is one remaining issue, that is, that I cannot get System Report to correctly show the disk as NOT removable. It seems theres a removable bit that I cannot figure out how to flip to false.

NB: I tried BootIt from Lexar in windows. It works fine in windows but for some reason has no effect on OSX.

Hope this helps.